# Disable focus outside the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, focus, tabindex

I'm making a web-page based application which would have keyboard (a joystick) only navigation. I use tabindex, but I also need to disable focus on the address bar, search bar or anything else outside the page.

This app would be run only on one specific device, so it's okay (actually needed) to disable some functionality.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a cool problem to solve.

**EDIT** : Added the backward  [shift]+[tab].

Try this script, ([working Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/ecbLou9c/)):

```
var firstInputObj;
var lastInputObj;

$("input").each(function(){
    if($(this).attr("tabIndex")=="1"){
        firstInputObj=$(this);
    }
    lastInputObj=$(this);

});
$(firstInputObj).focus();

// tab (forward)
$(lastInputObj).on("keydown",function(e){
    if(!e.shiftKey && e.which==9){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(firstInputObj).focus();
    }
});

// Shift tab (backward)
$(firstInputObj).on("keydown",function(e){
    if(e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 9) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(lastInputObj).focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!